# How to get broker details on connectionLost()

Tags: mqtt, paho

I am using eclipse paho java client to connect to mqtt broker.
Have written a subscriber client implementing MqttCallbackExtended.

I am getting connectionLost() callback. 
But how do I get to know that which broker lost the connection.

I have specified multiple uri's via setServerURIs() api of MqttConnectOptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified multiple brokers, they all should be part of the same cluster offering the same topic space.

This means you shouldn't need to care from the client side which broker you were connected to as the client will just move to the next in the list when it tries to reconnect.

But if you really need to know, then you can always log the URI when the connection is created using the information from the `connectionComplete()` callback on the `MqttCallbackExtended` class

Comment: I understand that, but still I need to know, say for logging purpose. Just need to know if there is a specific way?

Comment: The only way is to log/store the URI from `connectComplete()`  and reference that when the connection is lost.